# Why ajax loaded link not clickable on jQuery click event?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I called Ajax on button click, and I got response with link. Now I want to do some action on that link but I cant, why?

here is the ajax call:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".rateReset").click(function(){
     var data_item = jQuery(this).attr("data-item");
     var data_target = jQuery(this).attr("data-target");
     var me = this;
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likevoting.php?data_item="+data_item+"&data_target="+data_target+"&interchange=yes",
        success: function(data){
           jQuery(me).closest("div.rateWrapper").html(data);
        }
   });
});
```

I got response like:

some text **[link](http://#)** lorem ipsume...

Now I want to add click event on 'link' text, how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: because your page already loaded and you have to load click event. you can get click event along with your ajax link response then it will work.

Comment: If I will do this it will repeat every ajax call..

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
jQuery(".rateReset").click(function(){
```

to

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".rateReset", function(){
```

Comment: I already tried this, but no luck :(